# Using 'this' with formData to only post from current form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, multipartform-data

I have a file upload form:

```
<form class="uploadFile" name="uploadFile" method="post" action="process/uploadBuildImages.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="uploadImageButton">Upload Image</div>
  <input type="file" id="fileUpload" class="fileUpload" name="picture">
</form>
```

I am posting this form via ajax and formData like so:

```
var form = $('.uploadFile')[0];
var formData = new FormData(form);
```

The issue is that I have this same form output up to 4 times on the same page. I am making a CMS with blog posts and the upload image form is in each of the blog posts.

How can I target and post only from the currently posted form? I know its along the lines of using 'this.form etc but always struggle with .next / closest etc. Will look more into it soon.

If I only have one instance of this form on the page then it works fine, but otherwise I get a no file chosen error.

Thanks!

For reference, full JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.uploadFile').submit(function(){
    var form = $('.uploadFile')[0];
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process/uploadBuildImages.php",
        data: formData,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(response){
            // actions
        }

    }
  });
}):
```

And there is at least 4 of the same div structures on the page which follow the same format as:

```
<div class="blogtest" id="'.$postID.'">
    <div class="text">
        <div class="postoverlay"></div>
        <div class="buildtext" id="'.$postTextID.'">'.$convertedtext.'</div>
        <form class="uploadFile" name="uploadFile" style="display:$showUploadForm;" method="post" action="process/uploadBuildImages.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000000" />
            <div class="uploadImageButton">Upload Image</div>
            <input type="file" id="fileUpload" class="fileUpload" name="picture">
        </form>
        <form class="updatepost" id="'.$postContentID.'" method="post">
            <div class="editor">
                            <textarea name="muffin" id="'.$ckEID.'" class="ckeditor">'.$textFiltered.'</textarea>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You haven't shown us your full JS, but I believe the issue you are facing is the lack of context. You trigger the posting of the form via AJAX through a specific handler, and then you should post data from the form where the submit event (or whatever handler you have chosen to use) have originated from.

Comment: Updates the question with some more code. :)

Comment: Try doing: var form = $(this);

Answer (score 0):

Echoing the same diagnosis I have made in my comments, you lack context in your function call — your code basically submits the form data in all forms with the class `.uploadFile` regardless of which one is submitted:

```
var form = $('.uploadFile')[0]; // Problematic line
```

You should use `$(this)` to give it context upon the firing of the submit context, so that you only submit the form data from the form where the event originated from, and not all forms with the class instead. Therefore, you substitute:

```
var form = $('uploadFile')[0];
```

with:

```
// Alternative 1
var form = $(this)[0];

// Alternative 2
var form = this;
```

In other words:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.uploadFile').submit(function(){
    var form = this; // Fixed line
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process/uploadBuildImages.php",
        data: formData,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(response){
            // actions
        }
    }
  });
});
```

You can learn more what `$(this)` does in jQuery [here](http://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified) and [here](http://coding.abel.nu/2013/04/this-and-this-in-jquery-callbacks/).